# Kubuntu 16.04.1 cannot get intel 3165 wireless adapter to work?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, intel-wireless

Quite unexperienced with Ubuntu installs, I've installed kubuntu and found that my wireless card (intel 3165) isn't working, the laptop is a hp pavilion x360. I'll quickly list the main forum solutions I tried to cut down on repeats (I did have these here but it kept marking the question as spam, I'll try to add them in later). Thanks for any help.

I'll include what seems like important information (let me know if there is anything else that would help).

`lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)`

`ls /lib/firmware | grep 7265
iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-15.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode`

`dmesg | grep iwl
[   13.147484] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   13.240037] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 19.324151.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.019671] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[   14.020309] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.020752] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.093583] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   14.095422] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   30.009118] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   30.009560] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   30.072323] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   30.072766] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   82.403679] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   82.404292] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   82.466903] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   82.467459] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   98.183044] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   98.183489] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   98.245344] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   98.245938] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1937.662352] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1937.662974] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1937.725344] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1937.725899] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled`

`ifconfig
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:4a:3e:a8:cb:82
          inet addr:192.168.0.29  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1653:c016:f400:8d3e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:173118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:150358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:222919025 (222.9 MB)  TX bytes:11772531 (11.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:387956 (387.9 KB)  TX bytes:387956 (387.9 KB)`

And here is the entire `cat wireless-info.txt` result. (sorry if its a bit hard to read, it was weird to format)

```
########## wireless info START ##########  
`Report from: 29 Aug 2016 13:03 ACST +0930  
Booted last: 29 Aug 2016 00:00 ACST +0930  
Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000 ` `
##### release ###########################  
`Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial  `
##### kernel ############################  
`Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  
Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7  `
##### desktop ###########################  
`/usr/share/xsessions/plasma  `
##### lspci #############################  
`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi  
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:80d1]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169  `
##### lsusb #############################  
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:2279 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0379 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100  
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2a70:f00e  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  `
##### PCMCIA card info ##################  
##### rfkill ############################  
`0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no  `
##### lsmod #############################  
`acer_wmi               20480  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
sparse_keymap          16384  3 acer_wmi,hp_wmi,intel_hid
wmi                    20480  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915_bpo,acer_wmi  `
##### interfaces ########################  
`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback  `
##### ifconfig ##########################  
`enp0s20f0u2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s20f0u2' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.236  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8a35:bbd6:80a5:1108/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3459 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6474114 (6.4 MB)  TX bytes:495942 (495.9 KB)  
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF3]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B) ` 
##### iwconfig ##########################  
`lo        no wireless extensions.  
enp0s20f0u2  no wireless extensions.  
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.  
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on  `
##### route #############################  
`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s20f0u2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s20f0u2
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s20f0u2  `
##### resolv.conf #######################  
`nameserver 127.0.1.1  `
##### network managers ##################  
`Installed:  
        NetworkManager  
Running:  
root      2822     1  0 12:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon  `
##### NetworkManager info ###############  
`GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20f0u2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Android
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Android
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20f0u2' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/net/enp0s20f0u2  GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20f0u2
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       4f59189c-5164-43ea-8b84-c639d94d1e29
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4f59189c-5164-43ea-8b84-c639d94d1e29 | Wired connection 2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.236/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.236
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1472513530
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = HPjosh
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::8a35:bbd6:80a5:1108/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                              
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS:   
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 3165 (Dual Band Wireless AC 3165)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-31-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               16.242414.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS:   
SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  *   `
##### NetworkManager.state ##############  
`[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true  `
##### NetworkManager.conf ###############  
`[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq  
[ifupdown]
managed=false  `
##### NetworkManager profiles ###########  
##### iw reg get ########################  
`Region: Australia/Adelaide (based on set time zone)  
country 00: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)  `
##### iwlist channels ##################  
`lo        no frequency information.  
enp0s20f0u2  no frequency information.  
enp3s0    no frequency information.  
wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz  `
##### iwlist scan #######################  
`Sorry, try again.
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.  
enp0s20f0u2  Interface doesn't support scanning.  
enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.  
wlp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down  `
##### module infos ######################  
`[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     49DC02934CB3D8C312FF8E1
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)  
[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)  
[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     651BF6CBF283F6F817B8F3A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)  
[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)  `
##### module parameters #################  
`[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y  
[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500  
[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y  
[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00  `
##### /etc/modules ######################  
##### modprobe options ##################  
`[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci  
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac  
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off  
[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211  
[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en  `
##### rc.local ##########################  
`exit 0  `
##### pm-utils ##########################  
##### udev rules ########################  
##### dmesg #############################  
`[   19.056565] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   19.060001] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   19.117254] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[   19.117336] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   28.010045] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[   28.110030] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   92.338452] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[   92.434109] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  360.895740] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[  360.990006] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  430.522674] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[  430.617190] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  432.339340] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[  432.434631] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  753.877208] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[  753.971437] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  940.322853] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 enp0s20f0u2: renamed from usb0
[  940.340038] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u2: link is not ready ` 
########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Unfortunately I had to cut out some background so that it wouldn't mark the question as spam, but basically I've tried all the previously successful solutions (particularly from this forum) and none have worked.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up that code chilli. To be a little more specific, I have tried downloading all the drivers from a git repository, I've tried turning off secure boot and I've tried updating/upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading drivers or firmware isn't going to fix this:

```
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: yes
     Hard blocked: no
```

It is unlikely that your laptop is *both* an HP and an Acer. Let's try to fix it. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear your result.

Comment: Worked beautifully, thankyou so much! If you're interested heres the new rfkill list:
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
           Hard blocked: no  

(I still have no idea how to format multiline code, I've seen that you're meant to use 4 spaces but it doesn't seem to work for me, I apologise)